# How to display file not found?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using this in Python 3.6:

```
filetest="test.txt"
with open(filetest,"r") as file:
```

How should I make Python console to display "File not available"  as an output if no input on the filetest is detected?
(such as there is no test.txt in the directory)

Comment: Put a `try/except` block or check the presence of the file before hand using `os` or `path` module

Comment: Add try/except block and also catch `FileNotFoundError` if the file you want to read is not exists. Catch a bare exception is not a good habit for all programming language.

Comment: `'test.txt'` is a string with a file name, `test.txt` is the attribute `txt` of the object `test`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just wrap it in a `try-except` block, and if there is no file named "test.txt" then you will print the message:  "File not available".

A simple example is:

```
filename="test.txt"
try:
    with open(filetest,"r") as file:
        pass
except OSError as e:
    print("File not available")
    print(e.strerror)
```

I added the `OSError` because it indicate problem in file handling where you can read about in the following link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html

One can also use the `FileNotFoundError` exception.

Comment: You need something in the `with` block (even just a `pass` if you don't need to use the file) to make this syntactically legal.

Comment: Blank except clauses aren’t necessarily something to encourage ... perhaps be more specific with the `except` clause ... here you’ll happily catch all sorts of other errors in the `with` block

Comment: @ShadowRanger correct, originally I has a print which want added to the answer!

Comment: @donkopotamus You are right, added the `OSError` exception and added a link for the user to read about built-in exceptions

Comment: The broader exception is good. You could `except OSError as e:` and then `print(e.strerror)` so that you don't mask a different problem with an assumed no-such-file.

Comment: @tdelaney Correct, this is why I used the `OSError` but added the option of a more specific exception.

Answer (score 2):

use `try-except` a simple sample has given below:

```
filename = 'test.txt'
try:
    with open(filename,"r") as file:
        read_file = file.read()

except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try-except blocks are what you look for.

```
try:
    filename=test.txt
    with open(filetest,"r") as file:
        print('File is available')
except EnvironmentError: # any IOError or OSError will be captured
    print('File not available')
```

Comment: The exception clause is very “wide” ... catching exceptions that may have nothing to do with opening the file ... for example, the current code will have an error before you even attempt to open the file ...